# Different heading sizes for different platforms in design tokens

Tags: bootstrap, design-system, design-tokens

Currently I'm doing an experiment with my first Design System(I have chosen Bootstrap) and Design Tokens([Style Dictionary](https://amzn.github.io/style-dictionary/#/README) npm module)

I configured and build all good,

Later I wanted to achieve as follows, `<h1>` font size to be different for web and devices.
I know `media query` handle this requirement some extend. Is there any other way to handle this?

Comment: Hi, this question is about web development, you might receive better answers at StackOverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css

Comment: @Izquierdo design-system design-tokens tags not available there, so thought to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways forward, and you've mentioned `@media` queries already--though that's not the easiest way.

I'm stealing the best answer from StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431411/pure-css-to-make-font-size-responsive-based-on-dynamic-amount-of-characters

You can use this to change font-size based on viewport width:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 16px; /* Default for browsers that don't support calc() or vw */
  font-size: calc(12px + 0.9vw);
}
```

You can also use clamp() for something even easier, but check the browser usage against your needs, as it has less support than above.

```
h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-size: clamp(2rem, 4vw, 2.5rem); /* min, default, max */
}
```